# You have an error in your SQL syntax (but there is no error)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mariadb

JDBC gave me this error.

> Grave:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO `entitytwitterusertofollow`
>   VALUES(0,NULL,NULL,1018880775335436288,F' at line 2

I have a huge Java String with a thousands of lines like this :

```
INSERT INTO `entitytwitterusertofollow` VALUES(0,NULL,NULL,984815801063571456,FALSE,1);
INSERT INTO `entitytwitterusertofollow` VALUES(0,NULL,NULL,1018880775335436288,FALSE,1);
INSERT INTO `entitytwitterusertofollow` VALUES(0,NULL,NULL,845199742065827841,FALSE,1);
INSERT INTO `entitytwitterusertofollow` VALUES(0,NULL,NULL,1018871764624035840,FALSE,1);
INSERT INTO `entitytwitterusertofollow` VALUES(0,NULL,NULL,811280845638090752,FALSE,1);
INSERT INTO `entitytwitterusertofollow` VALUES(0,NULL,NULL,1018804045635641344,FALSE,1);
INSERT INTO `entitytwitterusertofollow` VALUES(0,NULL,NULL,1018784953839038464,FALSE,1);
```

But if I debug, view my String, save it in a file, and then import it in MariaDB, everything is fine.

What's wrong with JDBC?

Comment: `NUUL`? Is that your actual error message? If it is, then NUUL is clearly incorrect. If it is not, then post the actual error message.

Comment: I edit my error message, i did fix this a moment ago, but it is still not working, but in MySQL it works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using **bad code** actually...

In JDBC, we should use `addBatch(sql);` the perform this kind of operation.

```
for (...) {
    final String sql = "INSERT INTO `entitytwitterusertofollow` (ENTITYUSERID, ENTITYTWITTERCONCURRENT_ID) VALUES("+ id + "," + concurrent.getId() + ");";
    statement.addBatch(sql);
}

statement.executeBatch();
conn.commit(); // if needed
```

Comment: You don't need to execute it as a batch, using `executeUpdate` in a loop will also work (it might be less efficient, but not necessarily).

Comment: Yes it is working, but I guess performance are better using this way. If I understand right, it does not send anything to database until `commit()` comes, `executeUpdate()` sends to it but does not commit right away... Which explains the performance gain.